# How to get attribute value from .Net WebControl?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-webcontrol

For example I have a web control being created the following way:

```
<dnwc:TestControl runat="server" CurrentSite="test"></dnwc:TestControl>
```

How would I get the value of CurrentSite in code behind(TestControl.cs)? I tried to get the value by doing:

```
this.Attributes["CurrentSite"]
```

But the value is null.

**SOLUTION:**

Since i can't post an answer, I will add it here.

I had to declare the attribute in the TestControl.cs file:

```
public string CurrentSite
    {
        get
        {
            string s = (string)ViewState["CurrentSite"];
            return (s == null) ? "test2" : s;
        }
        set
        {
            ViewState["CurrentSite"] = value;

            //Retrieve the current site and set it as an attribute in the input tag
            inputTag.SetAttribute("data-current-site", value);
        }
    }
```

Unfortunately I could only access the value after it has been set. The value gets set after the instance has been created. So after the constructor gets called. Originally I needed the value to be set in a method that the constructor calls but this will do for now.

Comment: "this" refers to the Page control...

Comment: @IrishChieftain: `this` refers to the current instance of an object.  According to the question, that code is in `TestControl.cs`, which presumably isn't the `Page` object.

Comment: I misread, thanks for correction David :)

Answer (score 2):

1) Give an ID to the `WebControl`

```
<dnwc:TestControl runat="server" CurrentSite="test" ID="testControl"></dnwc:TestControl>
```

2) You can use the `Page.FindControl(string id)` to get the `Control` from the Page code behind

```
Control webcontrol = FindControl("testControl");
```

2) Cast the `Control` to `TestControl` and get the `CurrentSite` property value.

```
string currentSite = ((TestControl)webcontrol).CurrentSite;
```

Comment: solution 2 it s the best!